# Force gulp task to completion via command line

Tags: jenkins, gulp

I have a `gulp` task that runs a couple other tasks.  One of the tasks is to run karma.  A couple of the tests are failing, which causes the `gulp` to fail.  Is there a way to force a `gulp` task to completion via the command line, or a way to manipulate the return code?

I am writing a Jenkins job for another project that I don't own, so I am not responsible for the failing tests.  That said, I don't have commit privs to the SVN repo that their code is stored on. Yes, it would be easiest to just change the gulpfile, but I'd rather not write a script in the Jenkins job to append a new task.  Although, that might be the only option.

Comment: The tasks are failing...?  Sounds like you need to fix your tasks instead.  :P Consider posting your code.

Comment: Added some more context.  Initially I just wanted to know if there was an easy way to force Gulp to return a successful status code instead of an error code.  I guess not. So here is a more specific set of circumstances.

Comment: gulp, it would appear, has some async support also. Perhaps worth a look? https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a 'gulp-native' way to do this. A very similar scenario to what you laid out is discussed in this [gulpjs/gulp issue - Continue gulp on error? #75](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/75).

The ultimate resolution was to use [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber)